# Id undefined on onmouseover request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm asking a basic question: why this alert returns undefined?

HTML

```
<div id="spettacoli_div">
<img id="spettacoli" src="grafica/spettacoli.png" onMouseOver="spettacoliIn()">
</div>
```

JS

```
function spettacoliIn(){
var comparendo = $(this).attr('id');
alert(comparendo);
```

}

Comment: Thank you all! Strange that I didn't find such issues in javascript guides I read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the function is invoked the context (`this`) is equal to the global object (`window`), and `window` doesn't have an id.

Instead of this, do

```
<img id="spettacoli" src="..." onMouseOver="spettacoliIn.call(this)">
```

The code that you use as an inline handler for the mouseover event runs with the correct context (`this` is the image element), but this does not automatically transfer to any calls the handler itself makes (i.e. calling `spettacoliIn`). You need to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to explicitly propagate the context.

Comment: Thank you very much. This fits my purposes very well.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the function is being called by window instead of the element. pass a parameter or catch the event parameter

```
function spettacoliIn (e) {
  // catch the event parameter
  var comparendo = (e || window.event).target.id;
  alert(comparendo);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="spettacoli_div">
<img id="spettacoli" src="grafica/spettacoli.png" onMouseOver="spettacoliIn(this)">
</div>
```

will work. 
The onMouseOver will not give jQuery the information about the current DOM element.

Change your spettacoliIn method to

```
function spettacoliIn(domElem){
   var elem = $(domElem);
   var comparendo = elem.attr('id');
   alert(comparendo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` is `window`. If you really want to use an inline event attribute you'd need to set `this` explicitly to the DOM element when calling the function, which you can do from inside the `onMouseOver` because at that point `this` *is* the element:

```
onMouseOver="spettacoliIn.call(this)"
```

But you're using jQuery, so why not bind the handler with jQuery and then `this` will be set automatically to the element in question:

```
$("#spettacoli").on("mouseover", function(e) {
     var element = $(this);
     // do something

});
```